Groups having exactly two non real-valued irreducible characters
Please note, I have posted a version of this question on MO. If you have comments or contributions, you might want to look there instead.
Suppose the finite group $G$ has exactly two conjugacy classes that are not self-inverse (a conjugacy class is self-inverse if the elements in it are conjugate to their inverses). Let $x$ be an element of one of these classes, and suppose $x$ has order 4. Then the order of the centralizer $C_G(x)$ is a square.
Can anyone give a group-theoretic proof?
A simple proof using characters is as follows: As is well-known, $G$ has just two non-real valued ordinary irreducible characters, label them $\chi$ and $\bar\chi.$ Write $\chi(x)=a+ib$ where $a,b\in\mathbb R.$ Since $x$ has order 4, then $a,b\in\mathbb Z.$ Now $0=\sum_{\psi\in\mathrm{Irr}(G)}\psi(x)^2$ and $|C_G(x)|=\sum_{\psi\in\mathrm{Irr}(G)}|\psi(x)|^2,$ and subtracting gives $|C_G(x)|=4b^2.$
The smallest example of such a group $G$ is the cyclic group of order 4. A nontrivial example is given by the group SmallGroup(3*64,1492) in the GAP small groups library. In this group, the non-real elements have centralizers of order 16. It is worth noting that the centralizer order is always a power of two, since if $x$ commutes with $y$ of odd order, then $xy$ cannot have order 4 and so is self-inverse, which implies the contradiction that $x$ is self-inverse. The difficulty is showing that the order is an even power of 2.

I think the semidirect product $C_5\rtimes C_4$, where we identify $C_4=Aut(C_5)$ (i.e. the holomorph), is also an example. The elements of order four generate their own centralizers. The conjugate pair of non-real characters are linear, $\chi(x)=\pm i$ for these elements $x$.

@JyrkiLahtonen Agreed. Note your example has the non-real character values purely imaginary ($a=0$ in my notation). This always seems to be the case, but I can't prove it.

I find this question cool, hence the bounty. If you spot another interesting question (totally unlike any banal homework problem), do bring it up at the Pearl Dive. I cannot cater to all requests (my taste can be sampled from the questions I have bountied in the past). But something needs to be done to revitalize that chat room (or, concede that the idea cannot work on this site).

Ok, so the bounty didn't help. May be the question is very difficult? May be you can ask the same question at MathOverflow? If you do, please link the two versions to each other so that viewers of either variant know what was discussed on the other.

Thanks @JyrkiLahtonen for setting up the bounty. I think the question might be very difficult - given your suggestion I'll ask a version of the same question on MathOverflow and link back to this one. Thanks again for your support of this question!

@JyrkiLahtonen, I have posted a version of this on MO at https://mathoverflow.net/q/479178/313687. As the only contributor, do you approve to close this question here?

I don't see a reason to close the question. Maybe someone finds it in 6 years and has a nice answer, and then everyone who comes to this page later can find it.

I don't see a need to close this question either. I haven't contributed anything, really, so I won't mind it if you decide to delete it (you cannot "close" it single-handedly, I think). You could delete it because there are no answers. But that's not usually done either (I think I know the customs quite well as I served as an elected moderator for three years). You see, concerned citizens could later decide to "undelete" it. Read that fine print :-)

Wishing the best of luck with the MO variant. I probably want to check it out every now and then. Because the link is here, deleting this would make such revisits more difficult. Really, there's no need for you to do anything about this variant. Don't worry about it becoming "litter", somehow (if that was your concern).
